# Header is present and I can click on header, but I am not able to see it when I run it on browser

Tags: yii2

I have written code in yii2 and include header.php and footer.php separate file in layout folder and include those file in main.php, which is also present in layout folder but when I run the file, I can see the footer but not header but header is present I can randomly click at header part and some login and sigup button got clicked. But not able to see that header.

I have tried including all images, CSS and JS file in layout folder but stil it didn't work and also I have included $layout in sitecontroller but still nothing works.

```html
<header>
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <div class="navBar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
          <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-xs"><img src="images/r-logo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></a>
        </aside>
        <aside class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
          <div id="cssmenu">
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Write Itinerary </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- Slider Banner -->
<section class="mainSlide">
  <div id="banner" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="overLay"></div>
      <img src="images/slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="overLay"></div>
      <img src="images/slide2.jpg" class="img-responsive"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="smallDevice">
    <h1 class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Find the perfect Trips & Itineraries</h1>
    <p class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <a class="open-mypage1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search Here</a>
  </div>
  <div id="mypage-info1" class="slideForm"> 
    <a href="#" class="up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <div class="bannerCaption">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="hidden-xs">Find the perfect Trips & Itineraries</h1>
        <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <ul class="filterForm">
          <li>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Continents">
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Select your country ">
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Select your city ">
          </li>
          <li>
            <button>Search</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Main file:

```php
<?php
  /* @var $this \yii\web\View */
  /* @var $content string */
  use yii\helpers\Html;
  use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
  use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
  use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
  use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
  use frontend\widgets\Metadata;
  use common\widgets\Alert;
  AppAsset::register($this);
  ?>
  <?php $this->beginPage() ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">

  <head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
      <meta name="google-site-verification" content="_LfxXaxrGXxez14d8E2Q8RpIqtoWC7-ZXEW_ylyxsqU" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('images/favicon.png');?>" />
      <?php $this->head() ?>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/owl.carousel.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/owl.theme.default.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/fonts.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCB0tU77lobH0Aq7RZXpOM__TvXaTSmqso&libraries=places"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
    <!--START HEADER-->
    <?php  include_once('header.php'); ?>
    <!--END HEADER--->
    <!--VIEW BODY-->
    <?php echo $content; ?>
    <!--END BODY-->
    <!--START FOOTER-->
    <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
    <!--END FOOTER-->
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
  </body>

  </html>
  <?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

There is no error, just not able to see the header but able to click by clicking randomly at header part.

Comment: you have everything mixed up in your html, do you know about working with HTML structure

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That was some error due to copying code from my editor to stack overflow. I know working with HTML structure. Can you help me figuring this thing out?

Comment: Ok that makes it clear, added an answer see if that helps you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have the `header.php` and `footer.php` file in the `layouts` directory. If that is correct you need to use the `render()` method rather than using `include_once`.

See below code how to include the header & footer files, i assume you have these files inside the `@frontend/views/layouts` directory, otherwise adjust the path.

**Note: you should avoid using shortcode like `<?php=?>` and use `<?php echo ?>` instead.**

```
<?php
    /* @var $this \yii\web\View */
    /* @var $content string */
    use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage()?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="<?php echo Yii::$app->language ?>">

  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php echo Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php echo Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
      <meta name="google-site-verification" content="_LfxXaxrGXxez14d8E2Q8RpIqtoWC7-ZXEW_ylyxsqU" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('images/favicon.png'); ?>" />
      <?php $this->head()?>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/owl.carousel.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/owl.theme.default.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/fonts.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCB0tU77lobH0Aq7RZXpOM__TvXaTSmqso&libraries=places"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php $this->beginBody()?>
    <!--START HEADER-->
    <?php echo $this->render('@frontend/views/layouts/header.php'); ?>
    <!--END HEADER--->
    <!--VIEW BODY-->
    <?php echo $content; ?>
    <!--END BODY-->
    <!--START FOOTER-->
    <?php echo $this->render('@frontend/views/layouts/footer.php'); ?>
    <!--END FOOTER-->
    <?php $this->endBody()?>
  </body>

  </html>
  <?php $this->endPage()?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it really works, i have manually included js file in appAsset file, some other functionalities works from there.